# Android Layout Inspector fails with timeout error

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

When I try to inspect my application's layout in a simulator, by going `Tools` => `Layout Inspector`, it always fails with one of the errors:

1.

> Error obtaining view hierarchy: There was a timeout error capturing the layout data from the device.
>       The device may be too slow, the captured view may be too complex, or the view may contain animations.
>
> Please retry with a simplified view and ensure the device is responsive.

2.

> No active windows displayed by com.instabridge.android.dev

The layout is not particularly complex, and it does not contain animations, just map with some views. Android Studio is 3.4.1. How do I fix it? Or how to find the cause of the errors?

Comment: update android studio.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Found a really strange solution.

Open your app, go to android home screen, open another app, now use Layout inspector in Android Studio.

It worked and I see my app's view hierarchy.

**UPDATE**

P.Melch claims that you don't even need to open another app, try just sending your app to background.

Comment: super thanks! btw, you don't even need to open another app. just send the app to the background..

Comment: I still get the first error, timeout error. I use Android Studio 3.5.3 and Win 10.

Comment: It doesn't works for me. I send the app to background but this error still occurs

Comment: @Simon Moshenko this answer is not working for me, can you please update your answer. I have added bounty of 50 points for this question too.

Comment: @HarishGyanani sorry I have nothing to add to the answer, hope someone else can help you

Comment: Hi, @SimonMoshenko. Thank you for your solution, and it works! I'm so curious why this is happening. I'm having this error only in certain app and still it is happening in Android Studio 3.6.1 Are you in the same situation as me?

Comment: @JoonSooPark hi! I actually have no idea, it was discovered by experimenting.

Comment: I had the same problem with a real device, but the workaround fixes it also. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on *Android Studio 3.4*, but I was able to use the Layout Inspector on *Android Studio 3.5 Beta 1* without any problems.

I am working with a very complex view, so I suspect that is what led to the trouble on *Android Studio 3.4*. Both the failure I saw and the success were with a physical device.

Comment: I have installed 3.5 Beta 3, and the errors persist. Tried both with simulator and real device. Tried different views.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a real device instead of the simulator.
When running the simulator and android studio, your laptop/mac/whatever might be running out of memory.

I always prefer to run the layout inspector on a real physical device. It works the same as with the emulator once you're connected with adb

Comment: Tried the same with a real device, same errors. I have 10 Gb used from 16