# In Android Studio, how can I get the Layout Inspector to display more complex views?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I'm writing automated UI tests for an Android app. However, sometimes the Layout Inspector fails to show the view hierarchy and instead displays an error:

> Error obtaining view hierarchy: There was a timeout error capturing the layout data from the device. The device may be too slow, the captured view may be too complex, or the view may contain animations.
>
> Please retry with a simplified view and ensure the device is responsive.

I've tried the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263347/android-layout-inspector-fails-with-timeout-error), but none have worked for me. I'm using Android Studio 3.5.2 and am running the app on a physical device.

Is there a way to get the Layout Inspector to display more complex views? Or is it possible to increase the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an unorthodox solution: Layout Inspector *sometimes* works when the app is sent to the background. The views will be shown as inactive, but it will still be possible to see their properties.